# How to specify to wp-cli for the `wp config create` (`wp core config`) command that the DB user is an 'all hosts' user?

Tags: wp-cli

My `wp config create` command:

```
wp core config --dbname=wordpress --dbuser=wordpress --dbpass='this is not the real password'
```

Running it:

```
$ wp core config --dbname=wordpress --dbuser=wordpress --dbpass='this is not the real password'
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'wordpress'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Some evidence about why I think the problem is that wp-cli is trying to use the '\@localhost version' of the user I'm specifying; from the MariaDB 'monitor':

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT Host, User FROM mysql.user;
+-----------+-----------+
| Host      | User      |
+-----------+-----------+
| %         | wordpress |
| 127.0.0.1 | root      |
| ::1       | root      |
| localhost |           |
| localhost | root      |
+-----------+-----------+
```

This didn't work either:

```
$ wp core config --dbhost=\% --dbname=wordpress --dbuser=wordpress --dbpass='this is not the real password'
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host '%' (8)
```

How can I tell wp-cli to use the '% version' of the *wordpress* user?

A seemingly relevant GitHub issue for the *wp-cli* project:

- [wp config create ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user · Issue #4505 · wp-cli/wp-cli](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/issues/4505)

Comment: Maybe: `--dbhost=\%` ? But it looks a bit wierd, in my opinion. I have never seen this before. Is `%` perhaps just a placeholder for `127.0.0.1`? Perhaps try with `--dbhost=127.0.0.1`. It's a long-shot. Sorry. :-/

Comment: @Zeth The '%' host means 'all hosts', i.e. that user can connect to the MySQL or MariaDB instance from any host. The '\@localhost' users can only connect from the same host as on which the DB server is running.

Comment: Ahh..! I see. But is the database on your local machine? The `dbhost` is telling the config, which host that the database is located on. So then you should insert the IP-address of the host where the database is located. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Zeth The database server instance is on my local machine. But it seems useful for the user to be able to connect from another host (other than the host on which the DB server instance is running), e.g. if I wanted to host the DB server and WordPress app on separate machines.

Comment: It turned out to be a dumb error; the password for the user in *wp-config.php* was missing the single quote character in it. I'm pretty sure I quoted it correctly in my `wp core config ...` command, but perhaps not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For users setup as an 'all hosts' user, i.e. the value of `Host` in the table `mysql.user` for the row for that user is `'%'`, there's nothing that needs to be done. *wp-cli* WILL try to connect as the 'localhost version' of that user, but doing so should be fine if the user really is an 'all hosts' user.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have an anonymous user ' '@'localhost' or ' '@'127.0.0.1' in MariaDB.
The recommended solution is to drop this anonymous user (this is usually a good thing to do anyways).

Comment: Would the anonymous user appear in the `mysql.user` table as having an empty or blank `User` column value (name)?

Comment: Yes, to remove it try 
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE User='';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Comment: It didn't help. `wp db check` still fails with `mysqlcheck: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'wordpress@%'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying to connect`. It seems like the *wp-cli* program just assumes all database users are the '\@localhost' versions.

Comment: Is remote access granted for user 'wordpress'?

Comment: How would I check whether remote access is granted? Isn't the `Host` column in the `mysql.user` table being `'%'` sufficient?

Comment: Ah, yes. '%' is enough. 
Well, let me think where problem could be.

Comment: See [my comment](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/318320/how-to-specify-to-wp-cli-for-the-wp-config-create-wp-core-config-command-t#comment470506_318320) on the question itself. I had effectively input the wrong password into *wp-config.php*.